# How to get the support fragment manager from ThemedReactContext?

Tags: android, react-native, android-fragments, react-context

### Environment

Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
  Node: 8.11.3
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4907809

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: ^16.4.2 => 16.4.2
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4

### Description

I'm writing a custom native android library that exposes a support fragment  for display. I created a simple view manager on the android side of react in which I return a placeholder layout (just a frame layout inside a parent linear layout to replace with the fragment layout later) in `createViewInstance` and later intend to add the library fragment inside `receiveCommand` on user action from the react side. However in order to add the fragment to the container I cannot get the support fragment manager from the `ThemedReactContext` obj that I capture in `createViewInstance`. Doing `themedReactContextObj.getCurrentActivity()` yields the deprecated `android.app.FragmentManager`. How do I get `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` instead in my view manager? Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code I'm working with based off a few solutions on SO & blogs on getting native fragments to display. It works if I use a `android.app.Fragment` to display instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`:

```
package com.awesome.awesomelib

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.awesome.awesomelib.AwesomeFragment;

import java.util.Map;

public class AwesomeViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<View> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTAwesomeView";
    public static final int REACT_COMMAND_CREATE = 1;

    private ThemedReactContext mContext = null;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected View createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {

        mContext = reactContext;

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(reactContext).inflate(R.layout.ll_awesomeview_container, null);
        return layout;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
        return MapBuilder.of("create", REACT_COMMAND_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveCommand(View view, int commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
        Log.d(REACT_CLASS, "receiveCommand: " + commandId);
        switch (commandId) {
            case REACT_COMMAND_CREATE:
                createFragment(view);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void createFragment(View view) {

        if(mContext != null) {

            // load the awesome lib fragment as container

            AwesomeFragment awFragment = new AwesomeFragment();
            //Here's where I'm stuck !!
            mContext.getCurrentActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fl_awesomeview_container, awFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

As getFragmentManager() is deprecated, how do I get the support fragment manager from the ThemedReactContext ?

Comment: I upgraded react native to the latest version and still have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who comes across this, it is currently not possible because `ReactActivity` does not extend `AppCompatActivity` which internally extends FragmentActivity which would then provide access to the support fragment manager. A pull request is open on react's github page that addresses this issue with timeline in sight yet for release.